# Integrate angular 4+ to HTML/Existing web app

Tags: angular

I want to integrate Angular(4+) to my existing project, I don't want to use SPA just a regular web application and using angular in some parts in my code (just like VueJS)﻿, is that possible?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by "integrate". You can try and deploy your angular app in separate directory and redirect to it from outter app and back. It will look wreid but probably will work.

Comment: Just with CDN with a normal HTML page and use it in a <script></script>